# How to disable auto window position in Win 10

Tags: windows-10

I'm annoyed with Win 10's auto window position, when I drag the window it'll move  window to strange position. How to disable it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem through the MSI True Color utility - Tools => Desktop Partition => untick the "Desktop Partition on" button..
I dunno if you can disable it through the windows settings though..

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 "snapping" settings that you can adjust to control the behavior:

- Sizing
- Relations
- Available space

I think that what you are describing, you want to turn off the Relations feature, but you can experiment with the others as well:

> `Settings -> System Settings -> Multitasking`

[image: Snap controls]